# Open modal by clicking on a button and hide modal by clicking on a close button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add a class to make a child `.modal-container` visible when clicking on the parent, which works, but then the second part of the code doesn't seem to work. e.g. when I click on the top right corner X sign `.close-modal` the modal doesn't disappear.

This is how the code looks like:

```
$(".animals-images").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".modal-container").addClass("show");
  });

$(".close-modal").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent(".modal-right").parent(".modal").parent(".modal-container").removeClass("show");
  });
```

This is how the `.show` class style on CSS looks like:

```
.modal-container.show {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

If on the last part of the jQuery code I put CSS `("opacity", "0");` instead of `removeClass` it works (but only once obviously). So I don't quite understand what is wrong here.

I wanted to do this in vanilla JavaScript, so if you have any idea how to do this it would be so much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="animals-images">
                <img src="./bianca.jpg"  class="animals-pictures" alt="">
                <div class="button-container">
                    <button class="click-me">Click Me!</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-container">
                    <div class="modal">
                        <div class="modal-left" style="background-image: url(./piggy.jpg);">
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-right">
                            <h2>Bianca</h2>
                            <button class="close-modal">X</button>
                            <p class="modal-paragraph">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, enim!
                                Aut odio nobis vitae tenetur assumenda sit enim quo explicabo!
                                Unde quaerat nisi ea minus laudantium voluptatibus ipsum qui quis!
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Consider that this is repeated 10 times (for 10 different images/modals), I am trying to find a way to do this with a few lines of code instead of selecting 10 individual times

Comment: Please show the html

Comment: Hi @dippas thanks for coming by. I have updated the question with the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (based on OP comment)**

> thanks for the answer @dippas , is there any way that I can make this code functional for many other images?

You've got to loop through each button then toggling class `show` on each event (`e.currentTarget`)

```js
const buttonsOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.click-me'),
  buttonsClose = document.querySelectorAll('.close-modal')

buttonsOpen.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show')))

buttonsClose.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.closest('.modal-container').classList.remove('show')))
```

```css
.modal-container {
  display: none
}

.modal-container.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="animals-images">
  <img src="./bianca.jpg" class="animals-pictures" alt="">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="click-me">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-left" style="background-image: url(./piggy.jpg);">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-right">
        <h2>Bianca</h2>
        <button class="close-modal">X</button>
        <p class="modal-paragraph">
          Modal 1
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="animals-images">
  <img src="./bianca.jpg" class="animals-pictures" alt="">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="click-me">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-left" style="background-image: url(./piggy.jpg);">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-right">
        <h2>Bianca</h2>
        <button class="close-modal">X</button>
        <p class="modal-paragraph">
          Modal 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a simple solution using vanilla JS

```js
const buttonOpen = document.querySelector('.click-me'),
  buttonClose = document.querySelector('.close-modal'),
  modal = document.querySelector('.modal-container')

buttonOpen.addEventListener('click', () => modal.classList.add('show'))

//this
//buttonClose.addEventListener('click', () => modal.classList.remove('show'))

//or this
buttonClose.addEventListener('click', e => e.currentTarget.closest('.modal-container').classList.remove('show'))
```

```css
.modal-container {
  display: none
}

.modal-container.show {
 display: block 
}
```

```html
<div class="animals-images">
  <img src="./bianca.jpg" class="animals-pictures" alt="">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="click-me">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-left" style="background-image: url(./piggy.jpg);">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-right">
        <h2>Bianca</h2>
        <button class="close-modal">X</button>
        <p class="modal-paragraph">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, enim! Aut odio nobis vitae tenetur assumenda sit enim quo explicabo! Unde quaerat nisi ea minus laudantium voluptatibus ipsum qui quis!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @dippas , is there any way that I can make this code functional for many other images?